# How to fetch custom post type by variable date?

Tags: functions

I'm designing a website for a DJ and one of the main functions of this website is to organize his upcoming events.

I've created a table that displays the next 7 days using some js, and the furthest left box always shows today's date in this format: 
"Thursday
December 1"

I want to grab all 'events' (from a custom post type I made) and put them in their rightful place in the table.

Ideally I can use a shortcode for each div (for each weekday) in the table to fetch that days events.

Here's what I have so far in trying to get just todays 'events' - it works in pieces but together fails. Also it's displaying an event that I deleted - I noticed if I delete the $the_query->the_post(); it will display the current events but it also infinitely loops. My attempt to show just todays events doesn't work either, it shows nothing while this is included (though I feel I'm close?)

```
// Add Shortcode
function custom_shortcode() {

    $today = getdate();
    $query = new WP_Query( 'year=' . $today['year'] . '&monthnum=' . $today['mon'] . '&day=' . $today['mday'] );
        // The Query
        $the_query = new WP_Query($args = array(
                'post_type' => 'events',
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key'     => 'event_time',
                'value'   => '$today',
                )
            )

            ) );

        // The Loop
        if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
            echo '<ul>';
            while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
                $the_query->the_post();
                echo "<div>";
                echo get_field('event_name') , "<br>";
            echo '<img class="myimage" style="max-width:180px;" src=',get_field('event_image') , ">" ;
            echo " <br>";
            echo '<div class="time">' , get_field('event_date_time') , "</div>" , "<br>";
            echo get_field('buy_ticket_button') , "<br>";
            echo "</div>";

            }


        }



}
add_shortcode( 'geteventname', 'custom_shortcode' );
```

EDIT: I've replaced the echo's with a return
Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First, I assume you store event date in custom field properly. Native WP post published dates are really not meant for future events, since future dates are used for scheduling functionality and make posts non–public.

From there it's just a matter of putting together appropriate `get_posts()`/`WP_Query` to retrieve your set.

Modern WP version allow very elaborate [meta queries](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters), including support for MySQL's DATE and DATETIME formats (though I highly recommend to store time as unix timestamps internally).

Comment: Okay, I can fetch my custom post items using a function shortcode to grab my custom field data using ACF and get_field .. I'm struggling to get those custom post items by date.

I think I need to add something like this to my shortcode: 

`$posts = get_posts(array(
 'numberposts' => -1,
 'post_type' => 'Events',
 'meta_key' => 'event_date_time',
 'meta_value_num' => '*how do I get todays time here*' ,
 'meta_compare' *I think I need one of these, help?'
));`

Comment: I've linked to respective documentation, had you went through `meta_query` part there? :)

Comment: thanks, I'm slowly understanding this better. I added the code I have so far and explained what it's doing. I'm going to keep reading and try and correct this myself - am I on the right path ?  lol

Comment: Since you are using `get_field()`, which isn't native WP function, it's probably down to what framework it's from and how it stores data / under which actual key name.